# It does not allow me to select buttons if javascript is in $(document).ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have two pieces of code in Jsfiddle. One works and the other one doesn't.

Now what happens is the user clicks on the the (Open Grid) link and selects a button, then in the text box selects the number of buttons the user wants to select. Then there are buttons below the text box where the user selects the number of buttons which matches the number in the text box (if more buttons are selected it would come up with an alert. Now this works in this Jsfiddle (click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ArX3r/)).

But it does not work in this jsfiddle (click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SUY9x/)). Now the only difference between the code is that in the non working JsFiddle the javascript is in the    `$(document).ready (function () {` while the other jsFiddle isn't. But I need the  $(document).ready (function () { because if not then the buttons which is suppose to appear below the textbox would not appear (it would appear in jsFiddle but not in my application so I need the `$(document).ready (function () {`.

So what needs to be done so that it would allow me to select the buttons under the text box yet I can still have the javascript  in the $(document).ready (function () {`.?

Thanks

Comment: You are calling `btnclick`, but it is not accessible because it was declared inside `$(document).ready()`. Move it outside.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer, you are both correct :). Also dzejkej is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `btnclick` inside a function: it is not visible in the global scope.

Move the functions out of the DOM-ready function, and define `currenttotal`; seems to work then.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/udCfA/)

Answer (score 0):

Functions should go outside of $(document).ready().  Event handlers can go inside.